# Dropdown list contol is overwritten by another control when loaded during the page load event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two dropdown list as part of a webform. If I load the list items during the page load event, the first list's selected value is set, but then overwritten by the second list's selected value being set. If I do the same during a non-page load event, they work fine. I am trying to figure out why the second list's selected value is overwriting the 1st during page load.

This is a C# asp.net web application. I am capturing an id from a previous page on page load (if present) and then selecting the dropdown values necessary on page load. If no id present then the user select's an option from a different drop down list and that populates the form fields and selects the appropriate values in the two relevant dropdown lists.

```
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Load_Courses();
            Load_Instructors();                

                try
                {
                    // Capture course id from another page
                    if (Request["course_id"] != null)
                        lstCourses.SelectedValue = Request["course_id"].ToString();

                    // Load selected course
                    if (lstCourses.SelectedValue != "")
                    {
                        course.Load(int.Parse(lstCourses.SelectedValue));
                        Load_Form(course);
                        Session["course"] = course; // Save course
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    course = new Course();
                    lstCourses.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    Clear_Form();
                    Session["course"] = null;
                }
            }
        }
```

```
Load_Form(Course course)
        {
            // Show course data
            txtName.Text = course.GetName();
            txtDescription.Text = course.GetDesc();
            txtStartDate.Text = course.GetStartDate();
            txtEndDate.Text = course.GetEndDate();           

            txtRegCloseDate.Text = course.GetDateToCloseRegistration();
            txtSeats.Text = course.GetNumberOfSeats().ToString();
            txtLocation.Text = course.GetLocation();
            lstInstructors.SelectedValue = course.GetInstructorId().ToString();

            if (course.GetAssistantInstructorId() != 0)
                lstAssistants.SelectedValue = course.GetAssistantInstructorId().ToString();
            else
                lstAssistants.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

lstInstructors.SelectedValue = 4 initially lets say, then when the lstAssistants.SelectedValue is set to a value, lets say 6, lstInstructors.SelectedValue is also set to 6. This does not occur when calling Load_Form() from outside page load event.

Comment: Something in `page_load` changed the return value of `GetInstructorId()` but you will need step by step debug to actually know what that is.

Comment: GetInstructorId() actually properly sets the lstInstructors.SelectedValue. Its not until course.GetAssistantInstructorId() is called that both lists have their selected value modified...